# Running animation in Phaser 3 does not work

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

We have to create a game with Phaser 3 for a university project. We opted for a classic jump and round game.

I chose individual scenes to achieve the 15 levels. Now I have encountered the problem that the run animation does not work in the scene for some reason. However, I don't know exactly why so at least it doesn't make sense to me that it doesn't work. Maybe someone has an idea or knows what I did wrong.

```js
// Level 1

var player;
var stars;
var bombs;
var platforms;
var cursors;
var score = 0;
var gameOver = false;
var scoreText;

class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {

    constructor (config) {
        super(config);
        //To use the scene in the game
        Phaser.Scene.call(this, { key: 'gamescene'});
    }
    
    preload () {
        this.load.image('sky', 'img/sky.png');
        this.load.image('ground', 'img/platform.png');
        this.load.image('star', 'img/star.png');
        this.load.image('bomb', 'img/bomb.png');
        this.load.spritesheet('dude', 'img/dude.png', { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 });
    }
    
    create ()  {

        //  A simple background for our game
        this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');

        //  The platforms group contains the ground and the 2 ledges we can jump on
        platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();

        //  Here we create the ground.
        //  Scale it to fit the width of the game (the original sprite is 400x32 in size)
        platforms.create(400, 568, 'ground').setScale(2).refreshBody();

        //  Now let's create some ledges
        platforms.create(600, 400, 'ground');
        platforms.create(50, 250, 'ground');
        platforms.create(750, 220, 'ground');

        // The player and its settings
        player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'dude');

        //  Player physics properties. Give the little guy a slight bounce.
        player.setBounce(0.2);
        player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

        //  Our player animations, turning, walking left and walking right.
        this.anims.create({
            key: 'left',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 0, end: 3 }),
            frameRate: 10,
            repeat: -1
        });

        this.anims.create({
            key: 'turn',
            frames: [ { key: 'dude', frame: 4 } ],
            frameRate: 20
        });

        this.anims.create({
            key: 'right',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 5, end: 8 }),
            frameRate: 10,
            repeat: -1
        });

        //  Input Events
        cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

        //  Some stars to collect, 12 in total, evenly spaced 70 pixels apart along the x axis
        stars = this.physics.add.group({
            key: 'star',
            repeat: 11,
            setXY: { x: 12, y: 0, stepX: 70 }
        });

        stars.children.iterate(function (child) {

            //  Give each star a slightly different bounce
            child.setBounceY(Phaser.Math.FloatBetween(0.4, 0.8));

        });

        bombs = this.physics.add.group();

        //  The score
        scoreText = this.add.text(16, 16, 'score: 0', { fontSize: '32px', fill: '#000' });

        //  Collide the player and the stars with the platforms
        this.physics.add.collider(player, platforms);
        this.physics.add.collider(stars, platforms);
        this.physics.add.collider(bombs, platforms);

        //  Checks to see if the player overlaps with any of the stars, if he does call the collectStar function
        this.physics.add.overlap(player, stars, collectStar, null, this);

        this.physics.add.collider(player, bombs, hitBomb, null, this);

    }
    
    update() {
        if (gameOver)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (cursors.left.isDown)
        {
            player.setVelocityX(-160);

            player.anims.play('left', true);
        }
        else if (cursors.right.isDown)
        {
            player.setVelocityX(160);

            player.anims.play('right', true);
        }
        else
        {
            player.setVelocityX(0);

            player.anims.play('turn');
        }

        if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down)
        {
            player.setVelocityY(-330);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, didn't I explain the problem well enough? Would be really important that someone can help me.

Comment: I don't see, where you are even creating the running animation, is it the left and right ??